# BigQuery: update a row with count of a subquery and inner join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have following two tables:

```
Table 1: Students
name:string,
age:integer,
class:integer,
number_of_allowed_trips:integer

Table 2: Trips
allowed_age:integer,
trip_name:string,
class:integer
```

I'm trying to assign for each student number of allowed trips based on some conditions. My query is:

```
UPDATE
  `mydataset.students` AS s
SET
  s.number_of_allowed_trips=(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    `mydataset.trips` AS t
  WHERE
    t.r.class= 9)
FROM
  `mydataset.trips` AS t
WHERE 
  r.name = 'Jack' 
  AND r.class = 9
  AND w.class = r.class
```

But this query doesn't work. What am I doing false? How can I get this code worked?

Comment: WHERE is allowed in UPDATE, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373922/14076891

Comment: Yes, it is allowed. But in your previous query there was a mistake. I can see you have fixed/edited that :-)

Comment: yes :) I meant, FROM is allowed in UPDATE

Comment: Thanks. Hope the query is working fine now !

Comment: For me it doesn't work... no rows are affected

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
  `mydataset.students` AS s
SET
  s.number_of_allowed_trips= (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    `mydataset.trips` AS t
  WHERE
    t.class = s.class
    AND s.age= 9  )
WHERE
  s.id=s.id
```

This works fine!