# Send SQL Server DataTable to Google Big Query

Tags: sql-server, database, google-bigquery

I want a solution to send a C# SQL Server DataTable to a Google BigQuery procedure to join it with another table and make an update.

I didn't find anything similar to what happens with SQL Server procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
  @MyTable MyTableType READONLY
```

but read that I could send JSON data to GBQ, then thought maybe I could use the `IReader` to create this JSON structure and send it to GBQ.

Then I could use this JSON data to make the join using syntax like the one described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373774/update-with-join-with-bigquery)

Is there a simpler way to accomplish such a goal? Something that does not require creating a temporary table to GBQ to join with it then?

EDIT:

- Found a solution, anyway if there is a soulution compliant with our requirements we would like to know.
- We'll keep working on it and share if we find something; I think that a solution can be found [using the UNNEST operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator).

---

**Solution**

We finally opted for a permanent table GBQ side to send data to and then making an update with the following update statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable MyTableAlias
SET MyTableAlias.Field1 = BrandNewTableAlias.Field1
FROM BrandNewTable BrandNewTableAlias
WHERE
    MyTableAlias.Field1 = BrandNewTableAlias.Field1;
```

GBQ does not allow for `UPDATE` statements on `JOIN` operations like SQL Server, therefore we had to use the syntax above, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373774/update-with-join-with-bigquery) on StackOverflow and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) on the Google Docs.

Comment: suggest you cut the solution and paste as an answer then accept it. Makes it a lot easier for others to know which question does/doesn't have a solution when looking through a list of search results.